# Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse as array in Laravel REST API

Tags: laravel, api

Here is my code. I am facing this error in Laravel REST API. Just I want to convert Laravel Blade to Laravel REST API. This code is working with Laravel Blade. I am trying to do it with Postman. But here this code is not working.

```
public function config()
{
    try {
        $data = [
            "ip" => '172.16.1.',
            "shade" => [
                "one"   => [
                    "from" => 0,
                    "to"   => 63,
                ],
                "two"   => [
                    "from" => 64,
                    "to"   => 127,
                ],
                "three" => [
                    "from" => 128,
                    "to"   => 192,
                ],
                "four" => [
                    "from" => 193,
                    "to"   => 257,
                ],
                "all" => [
                    "from" => 0,
                    "to"   => 257,
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return response()->json([ 'status' => true,
            'message' => "Configuration Done",
            'data' => $data
        ], 200);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // something went wrong while processing the request
        return response()->json([
            'error' => $e->getMessage()
        ], 500);
    }
}

public function getShade(Request $request){
    try {
        $config = $this->config();
        $base = $config["ip"];
        $curent_shade = $config['shade'][$request->shade];
        $from = $curent_shade['from'];

        $to = $curent_shade['to'];
        $ips_range = range($curent_shade['from'], $curent_shade['to']);
        $ips = [];

        foreach ($ips_range as $key => $value) {
            $ips[] = [
                "ip" => $base . $value,
                "mn" => $from + 1,
            ];

            $from++;
        }

        $data['ips'] = $ips;

        return response()->json([
            'data' => $data,
            'status' => true,
            'message' => "Sahde Selected Done"
        ], 200);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // something went wrong while processing the request
        return response()->json([
            'error' => $e->getMessage()
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working ? What response do you have in Postman ? Did you look in the error logs ?

Comment: Just I am getting this error in postman 

 Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse as array in file C:\xampp\htdocs\test-api\app\Http\Controllers\Api\LoomController.php on line 68

Comment: And what is in LoomController.php on line 68 ?

Comment: $base = $config["ip"];

Answer (score 0):

Your config function returns an `Illuminate\Http\Response` not an array, if it is not requested directly by the api just return the array, or insert your $data array in your getShade function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `config()` method returns a `response()`, which is [a full HTTP response](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#creating-responses).  But the `getShade()` method treats that response as an array - that won't work, it isn't an array.

```
public function config() {
    // ... your code
    // This returns a full HTTP response for a browser, not an array
    return response()->json([ 'status' => true,
                              'message' => "Configuration Done",
                              'data' => $data
    ], 200);
}

public function getShade(Request $request){
    try {
        // Here $config is a full HTTP request ...
        $config = $this->config();

        // ... but you are treating it like an array, won't work.
        $base = $config["ip"];
```

You could get around this by having your `config()` method simply return an array:

```
public function config() {
    // ... your code
    return [
        'status'  => true,
        'message' => "Configuration Done",
        'data'    => $data
    ];
```

Though if `config()` is really intended to return responses to browsers *as well* as other internal methods which will expect arrays, you'll need some logic to work out what kind of those responses to return.